# How can I use ImageTk.getimage without first opening a random image file?

Tags: python-imaging-library

ImageTk.getimage fails, but not if I first call ImageTk.PhotoImage successfully on ANY (I believe) image file.

I tried calling ImageTk.getimage on an image, but got the error message :
line 279, in getimage
photo.tk.call("PyImagingPhotoGet", photo, block.id)
tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "PyImagingPhotoGet"

Here is example code :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

gamma_code =  'R0lGODlhCgAMAIcAAP///9v//4/b////22a2////trZmAN'
gamma_code += 'uPOTmP29vb/wAAALb//7aPj7ZmZrZmOf+2Zo+2j49mj485'
gamma_code += 'OY85AP/bj2ZmOWYAOWYAANv/2zk5jzkAAABmtgA5jwAAZg'
for k in range(90) : gamma_code +=  'AAAAAAAAAA'
gamma_code += 'AAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAKAAwAAAhgAAEIHEgQAAUNHRYA'
gamma_code += 'OKCAAAAADDBIEFDgAgEAAAYkAGCAwIENAEKKdAAhQwAAKF'
gamma_code += 'M2qCAAgMuXAAwgAECzJoABEQIA2MkTwAMOAQAIHTpgAgIA'
gamma_code += 'SJMCKGBBAICnUKNKBRAQADs='

LAMBDA_code =  'R0lGODlhDQANAIcAAP///wAAAP//ttuPOWYAAP+2Zo/b/'
LAMBDA_code += '2a2/9v//wAAOQBmtrb//wA5j485AP//2//bj7ZmAI85Zm'
LAMBDA_code += 'ZmtrZmOTmP2zmPtjk5jwAAZgAAAAAAA'
for m in range(92) : LAMBDA_code +=  'AAAAAAAAAA'
LAMBDA_code += 'CH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAANAA0AAAiDAAEIHEiw4EABEgAoXM'
LAMBDA_code += 'gQwIALCwBInDjRQYMABwBo3LixQIUGDBAAGEly5AQDAxI'
LAMBDA_code += 'YAMCyJYAHFhAIIEABgM2bAAYcAAAAAgMEAIIGdRBhAQAA'
LAMBDA_code += 'BQIcAMCUaQEFAKIKIKAAgFUAAggcAMAVwIAEBgAAEEAgQ'
LAMBDA_code += 'AIDAAAUCMBWAYC3cOPGDQgAOw=='

def test(IM) :
    try :
        ImageTk.getimage(IM)
        print('SUCCESS')
    except : print('FAILURE')    
    
    
root = Tk()
A = PhotoImage(data = gamma_code)
print('image 1 dimensions : ',A.width(),',',A.height())

B = PhotoImage(data = LAMBDA_code)
print('image 2 dimensions : ',B.width(),',',B.height())

temp_file_name = 'wlqdkijqodmqqx9.f4r' #random digits
B.write(temp_file_name)    

print('\nattempt 1 : ', end = "")
test(A)

ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(temp_file_name))
print("\n'ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(temp_file_name))' has now been run.")

print('attempt 2 : ', end = "")
test(A)

os.remove(temp_file_name)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, with your example code I get `SUCCESS` for both attempt 1 and attempt 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying it. I get FAILURE for the first attempt, as you probably guessed.

Comment: I installed the latest version of Pillow (10.0.0), and now I get SUCCESS for both attempts.